# How does C++ recognize multi-line strings?

Tags: c++, compilation, lex

As we know, C++ has the following two ways of representing multi-line strings(In fact, there are other ways, but I only focus on these 2.):

```
std::string multiline_str1 =
        "Hello hello "
        "world "
        "by cpp.";

std::string multiline_str2 = "Hello hello \
world \
by cpp.";
```

I'm curious how c++ recognizes them as a string. Is it solved in the lexical analysis stage? Or is it solved in the syntax analysis stage?

If you can give me some blogs, or tell me what source code I should look at, I would be very grateful.

Comment: _"-...String literals placed side-by-side are concatenated at translation phase 6 (after the preprocessor)...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal#Concatenation .  Note that whitespace (newlines, spaces, comments) have already been transformed into a single space.

Comment: [Phases of translation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases), the first string is concatenated in phase 6 (after a lot of interesting translation has already happened), the second string is "concatenated" in phase 2 (very very early in the translation pipeline).

Comment: I'm curious as to why this matters to you?

Comment: My job is about static analysis of code. Now I want my scanner to ignore the contents of C++ strings, but there is a bug with multi-line strings. I'd like some references. @JesperJuhl